# API DATA Management: Extraction of metadata for Rooms

Tags: autodesk-forge

i have struggled to extract the data rooms from the Revit models when I am using the API Data Management process.

https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/developers_guide/overview/

Has also anyone had this problem? Many data is extracted. however, the data of the rooms or spaces is not.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Please note that Revit rooms are only extracted when a special flag is passed to the Model Derivative conversion: https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/new-rvt-svf-model-derivative-parameter-generates-additional-content-including-rooms-and-spaces.

Comment: Hi @petr ,thanks very much for the response. i have a doubt about it.
How can I integrate this process into the "Model Derivative 05"??
i have already created the whole process in postman and it extracts the data properly.
however, I would like to include the rooms / spaces in the process.

Comment: The only change needed is adding the `"generateMasterViews": true` property to the payload of the [POST job](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/jobs/job-POST/) endpoint. This is explained in the blog post.

Comment: thanks for your reply. however, I am a little bit lost here. I am not using any post in my process to extract the data, only for the access token.
I am using only the Task 1 and Task 4 of ModelDerivative_05

Comment: Ah, I guess your data is in BIM360 or ACC then, right? In that case, the translation (the `POST job` request) is actually done by the app itself. I'm not sure if these products include the `generateMasterViews` option when they kick off the conversion, though. If not, you'd need to run the conversion yourself one more time.